# How do I fix this migration error message in Ruby(Sinatra)

Tags: rubygems, sinatra, entity-framework-migrations, sinatra-activerecord, error-messages-for

I'm new to programming in ruby, started using Sinatra framework and while trying to develop a simple MVC application I tried to create a migration on my Terminal but I'm getting these error messages

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:73:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:73:in `rescue in block in require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `block in require'     
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/Programming practice/Ruby practice/JTasks_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' 
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/Programming practice/Ruby practice/JTasks_app/rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sinatra-activerecord
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'     
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/Programming practice/Ruby practice/JTasks_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' 
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/Programming practice/Ruby practice/JTasks_app/rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

These are my gems already installed
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rake'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'pry'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'faker'
gem 'rack', '~> 3.0.7'

These are gems in my Gemfile

This is the command I'm using to create the migration rake db:create_migration NAME=Create_users

Comment: I also have the same error related to 'require'